# Progressed smoothly in a game while not paying attention

Tags: psychology, multi-tasking

I was playing Flappy Bird trying to beat my highest score. While on one run (or fly, hehe) my friend got me engaged in a conversation. When the short conversation ended I found myself thinking about something for probably 10-15 seconds, where in this time my eyes were looking at the game on my iPad, and yet my actual attention was not on the game. I was deep in thought on the topic my friend had brought up. The moment I got back to reality, I tried to re-engage myself with the game, but within a few seconds I crashed the poor bird. I had broken my record, however. It was as if another side of me took over while i was busy thinking of something else on the side. I voluntarily tried to reproduce this situation but I failed at the multitasking (as I know some will call it). This has happened while doing other things too. How is this explained, and why can it not be reproduced voluntarily.

Comment: The phenomenon your experiencing is called "Flow" in psychology. It's currently being researched actively and isn't well explained yet.

Answer (score 3):

My interpretation of this question is that you are asking about divided attention. Some (normally easy) tasks can continue to be accomplished in conditions of [divided attention](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Attention#Multitasking_and_divided_attention), and with practice you should be able to control this.

I don't know of any research confirming your suggestion that you actually got better in such conditions. You could also look at recent studies on [mind-wandering](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mind-wandering) (which tend to show interruptions in the main task when you are thinking about something else) or the [passive/active mode](http://www.tandfonline.com/doi/abs/10.1080/13506280500193487) in visual tasks (in which, some argue, people actually get better when they don't concentrate as hard).